# oracle order column by adjacent values starting from median and adding outward on either side

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

It was difficult to come up with an appropriate title so hopefully this description and following example will make it more clear.

I have a table with a non-null column (but not a primary key) whose value is a five digit number stored as a string such as '00001', '00002', '00003', ..., '99999'. Not all numbers are be present (it is possible that the sequence is missing a number). I am trying to make a query such that if given the first two digits of the number, I can order the select statement according to the adjacent numbers starting from the middle value and working outward.

Here is an example (sql fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6908/8)) of what I need but unfortunately I can't use a case statement to order the results since the cases are unknown ahead of time and there could be quite a few.

```
select number_str_id from my_table
where number_str_id like '00%'
order by 
    case to_number(number_str_id)
        when 1 then 9
        when 2 then 7
        when 3 then 5
        when 4 then 3
        when 5 then 1
        when 6 then 2
        when 7 then 4
        when 8 then 6
        when 9 then 8
    end
    asc;
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(To long for a comment.)

Does this go in the right direction?

```
order by 
    case to_number(substr(number_str_id, 3, 1))
        when 1 then 9
        when 2 then 7
        when 3 then 5
        when 4 then 3
        when 5 then 1
        when 6 then 2
        when 7 then 4
        when 8 then 6
        when 9 then 8
    end,
    case to_number(substr(number_str_id, 4, 1))
        when 1 then 9
        when 2 then 7
        when 3 then 5
        when 4 then 3
        when 5 then 1
        when 6 then 2
        when 7 then 4
        when 8 then 6
        when 9 then 8
    end,
    case to_number(substr(number_str_id, 5, 1))
        when 1 then 9
        when 2 then 7
        when 3 then 5
        when 4 then 3
        when 5 then 1
        when 6 then 2
        when 7 then 4
        when 8 then 6
        when 9 then 8
    end
```

I'm not sure if I understand your logic here.